# Pentaho Report: Add two sections of Report Header and Details in pentaho report designer

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am creating a report with parameters in which I need to have two sets of headers and data to show data from two different tables, but in pentaho reports there is by default only one set of Report Header and Data.

Is there any way I can achieve the below???

[image]

Comment: can you describe your problem in a better way,also include the expected output.

Comment: Sure, I am working on a report which has parameters. Now, generally the report will have one table which will display data once all the parameter values have been provided. However, in this scenario, I am trying to have two tables one below the other in the report designer interface (two report headers and two details tab). I want to know how to have two tables one below the other in the report interface.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept called sub-report, you can add 2 inline sub-report inside main report(in group header) and specify two different data-source to get data and then adjust the layout.
it will look like below, if you don't understand then learn sub-report concept.

[image]

Comment: Actually, both my tables are coming from the same data-source. I am showing few columns from the data-source on one table and few columns on another table. I just need to have two table views in the same report once parameter values are entered.

Comment: I have joined the two different tables using a join condition in a single data source and getting the columns in two different reports. I want to know if I can see two reports in a single screen in pentaho.

Comment: @Kuldip.Das did you understood my answer? i am explaining the same, follow above things. run the report. you will able to see both the tables into one single page in single report.